# Blank Screen After X minutes

Tags: c#, .net

I don't think I am taking enough breaks and my eyes are kinda strained for being on the computer. I try to do the 20min rule as much as I can but once I  get into the zone I tend to forget to do it.

I want to whip up a quick app(if one exists please point me to it) that after 20 minutes(maybe 10second before a countdown) that will shut of the screen or blank it or something to force me to take a break.

Not sure if C# has the access to the apis to something like this and not sure if it should be a console app or wpf app or what. It would need to start up on startup and probably live in the task bar.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

If it it is too broad here is what I am after

1. Can C# blank a screen after X minutes? Then after X seconds return back to normal.
2. To do a timed task like this is it better to use something with a
   gui or could I get way with a console app(trying to get this up as
   fast as possible)

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Furthermore, it is a pretty bad idea to break your concentration every 20 minutes. This will hurt both your efficiency as well as the fun you have at work.

Comment: Well of course it sucks to break you concentration but it what sucks more is if you ruin your eyes and your health. If it becomes a problem I can always refine my idea and fix it. It is easier to fix then your health.

Comment: I agree... it takes 20 minutes to get in "the zone". Then once you break that concentration, you're 20 minutes away from optimal productivity.

Comment: The number can be tweaked(hence why the title is X minutes)...... I am using the recommend number that health professionals have suggested.

Comment: Here is an explanation of creating a "full screen" window in .NET. Note the usage of the Win32 API. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16618/How-To-Make-a-Windows-Form-App-Truly-Full-Screen-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WPF Application and Quartz.NET.

In this case you will able to add custom content to window e.g. clock and it will be displayed when screen will be blocked.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFBlankScreen.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"   
        WindowState="Minimized"
        Background="Orange" 
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
        >
    <Grid>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

        IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        map.Add("window", this);

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ShowJob>()
         .WithIdentity("showJob", "group")             
         .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
         .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("showTrigger", "group")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        sched.Start();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F11)
        {               
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

ShowJob class:

```
class ShowJob: IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Window win = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("window") as Window;
        if (win != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                win.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth;
                win.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
                win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                win.Topmost = true;
                win.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                win.Show();
            }));

            IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            map.Add("window", win);

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HideJob>()
             .WithIdentity("hideJob", "group")
             .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
             .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("hideTrigger", "group")
              .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(5, IntervalUnit.Second))
              .Build();

            context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

HideJob class:

```
class HideJob: IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Window win = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("window") as Window;          
        if (win != null && Application.Current != null)
        {               
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                win.Hide();
            }));
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I will try it and see if it works any better. Can it be forced unblocked if needed?

Comment: @chobo2 yes you can. I added code to my answer that when you press F11 key window will be immediately hide.

Answer (score 7):

To turn on/off you can use the following class:

```
  public static class MonitorHelper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        public static void TurnOn()
        {
            SendMessage(-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON);
        }

        public static void TurnOff()
        {
            SendMessage(-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);
        }

        const int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int MONITOR_ON = -1;
        const int MONITOR_OFF = 2;     
    }
```

Usage of `MonitorHelper` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MonitorHelper.TurnOff();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        MonitorHelper.TurnOn();
    }
}
```

If you want schedule your task with turn on/off monitor you can use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Example with Quartz.NET:

Job class:

```
class MonitorJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        MonitorHelper.TurnOff();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        MonitorHelper.TurnOn();
    }
}
```

Configuration code:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonitorJob>()
 .WithIdentity("monitorJob", "group")
 .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
  .WithIdentity("monitorTrigger", "group")            
  .StartNow()
  .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
  .Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

sched.Start();
```

MonitorHelper class with PostMessage:

```
class MonitorHelperEx
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static void TurnOn()
    {
        PostMessageSafe(new IntPtr(-1), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON);
    }

    public static void TurnOff()
    {
        PostMessageSafe(new IntPtr(-1), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);
    }

    static void PostMessageSafe(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        bool returnValue = PostMessage(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        if (!returnValue)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }

    static readonly IntPtr SC_MONITORPOWER = new IntPtr(0xF170);
    static readonly uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    static readonly IntPtr MONITOR_ON = new IntPtr(-1);
    static readonly IntPtr MONITOR_OFF = new IntPtr(2);     
}
```

Comment: Good Idea did not even think of using Quartz.

Comment: @chobo2 Quartz.NET is very good for schedule task, check my answer again, I added example code.

Comment: Ya. I used it before. It is great. Better than my original plan to use timers.

Comment: Hmm it does not seem to want to wake up after montior turns off. Never seems to go past that line

Comment: @chobo2 could you download and check BlankScreen solution http://sdrv.ms/Zne7Sa ?

Comment: hey. Still same problem I tired with and without quartz(so the first 3 lines of code that turn the monitor on and off). It turns off but not on. I am running windows 8 and the only way it comes back is if I move my mouse or hit "any key"

Comment: @chobo2 I made test on Windows7 and it's working very well, I don't have Windows8, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Hmm. Ok maybe someone else who has windows 8 can try. I also noticed that it only runs once and that seems to be it. Does not run again. I can try windows 7 but since 70% of the time I am in windows 8...it won't help me too much.

Comment: @chobo2 check my answer, I added new class MonitorHelperEx, you can try use it.

Comment: No it does not work and actually is worse than the orignal. I tried to turnOff and then TurnOn in the next line but my monitor never turns on not even with moving the mouse or anything have to do a hard restart to get a screen back.

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be fancy, but it is VERY simple, and it works:

In a new Winforms-project, do this:
- Set FormBorderStyle = None
- Set BackColor = Red (or whatever you want)
- Set TopMost = True
- Set WindowState = Maximized
- Drop a timer on the form
- Set timer Interval to 2000
- Set timer Enabled = true
- Doubleclick timer and write Close(); in the eventhandler.

Finished!

Edit; This only makes ONE screen bright red for two seconds, but you SHOULD be able to notice this....

Answer (score 0):

This is how you turn off your screen

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //to DllImport

 public int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
 public int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170; //Using the system pre-defined MSDN constants    
 that    can be used by the SendMessage() function .
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
//To call a DLL function from C#, you must provide this declaration .


  private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {

   SendMessage( this.Handle.ToInt32() , WM_SYSCOMMAND , SC_MONITORPOWER ,2 );//DLL    
   function
   }
```